# Variadic default parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I wanted to program a multidimensional map the other day and stumbled over the following problem. Normally, for a map, you need a `key`, a `cmp`(or `less`) and a `hash`-type. In a multidimensional map, you'd need one of those for each dimension of the map.

Now, how do you declare the map class? I tried the following:

```
template<typename val, typename ... key, typename ... cmp, typename ... hash>
class multimap;
```

For obvious reasons it didn't work so I came up with a workaround:

```
template<typename Key,
         typename Cmp = std::less<Key>,
         typename Hash = std::hash<Key>>
struct Dimension
{
  using Key = Key;
  using Cmp = Cmp;
  using Hash = Hash;
};
template<typename Val, typename ... Dimensions>
class multimap;
// Example usage:
multimap<float, Dimension<int>, Dimension<float, some_cmp_t>> my_map;
```

While this works, it forces the user to repeat `Dimension<...>` all over the place, which is unfortunate if he just wanted to declare a simple map, say `(int, int, int) -> float` which would look like `multimap<float, Dimension<int>, Dimension<int>, Dimension<int>>`. What can I do to make this more pleasing to the user?

Note, with the declaration like above, it also makes it impossible to deduce the type of a specific Dimension from a potential constructor that takes a Comparator for each dimension.

How can I make the declaration easy to use so that e.g.

- `multimap<float, int, int, int>` results in `(int, int, int) -> float`
- `mulitmap<float, Dimension<int, some_cmp_t, some_hash_t>, int>` results in `(int, int) -> float` using a special comparator and hash function on dimension one.

Comment: Like in [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72b310de45fdafda) ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, yeah. Now I feel like an idiot for not seeing such a simple solution with speczialition of a helper type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn non-dimensions into dimensions by passing each type through a helper trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct DimensionFilter
{
    using type = Dimension<T>;
};

template <typename Key, typename Cmp, typename Hash>
struct DimensionFilter<Dimension<Key, Cmp, Hash>>
{
    using type = Dimension<Key, Cmp, Hash>;
};
```

Then whenever you are referring to a parameter pack of `multimap`, use:

```
typename DimensionFilter<Dimensions>::type...
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72b310de45fdafda)

You can also make `multimap` an alias template, so that the actual type it refers to already receives only `Dimensions`:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename Val, typename ... Dimensions>
    struct multimap {};
}

template <typename Val, typename ... Dimensions>
using multimap = detail::multimap<Val, typename DimensionFilter<Dimensions>::type...>;
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1c030609dc5c826)